# headerlinesIn not working correctly in importdata MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab

I am importing some data from the excel and the code looks like this:

Code:

```
%Import Data
filename = 'Stocks.xlsx';
delimiterIn = ' ';
headerlinesIn = 1;
A = importdata(filename,delimiterIn,headerlinesIn);
```

The excel file looks like this:

[image]

When I read in the data, A looks like this:

[image]

I thought when the headerlineIn = 1, the first line should not read. Why is it that it is being read? How to avoid this?

Need some guidance..

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Actually `A` is a struct and what you are showing is `A.textdata` and in `A.data` should be the data you're looking for. If thats not case for you, please share your excel file.

Comment: The link is this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3kholw9derr0n1h/Stock%20Holdings.xlsx?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I thought your code is alright.

With your example file and your code I get a struct `A`.

```
A = importdata('Stocks.xlsx',' ',1);
```

In `A.data.Sheet1` is all the data correctly read:

[image]

And in `A.textdata.Sheet1` the appears what you posted you get.

[image]

So the problem must be something I can't reproduce.

---

Alternatively you could try if [**`xlsread`**](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html) works for you.

```
B = xlsread('Stocks.xlsx',1)
```

[image]

I get the same result as before.

---

I finally get your problem, you're not concerned about the data, you really want to skip the first line of the header in the means of `textdata`.

Well `headerlinesIn` just signalizes `importdata` when your data starts, respectively when it should start to read actual data. **Everything else**, which is then declared not to be data, is put into `A.textdata.Sheet1`, also the first line. So the code works as intended.

If you want to get rid of the first line of your header, you could apply the following line:

```
N = 2;  %// number of columns before data starts
A.textdata.Sheet1 = {A.textdata.Sheet1{headerlinesIn+1:end,1:N}};
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for helping out. But I m not getting you.. So you have the same issue as mine? I don't want the first line in A.textdata.Sheet1.

Comment: @lakesh Now I get your problem - have a look at my edit.

Comment: Thanks again. Get what you are doing to get rid of the first line. But I thought that headerlineIn is used to skip the first line. Am i right?

Comment: @lakesh You would be right in terms of actual data. That is why this function is called `importdata`. That it also outputs all non-data is a "bonus-feature". Just imagine you would double your excel-data to 4 lines. For `importdata('Stocks.xlsx',' ',1)` it would then return the data of the 2nd and 4th line and save the rest in `textdata` and for `importdata('Stocks.xlsx',' ',3)` it saves just the 4th line as data and puts the whole rest, including the 2nd line in `textdata`. I don't know what more to explain, you could just try it out.